# MediaElement and native video player shows videos in wrong orientation

Tags: windows-phone-8, video, orientation, native, mediaelement

I have a problem while using `MediaElement` to play video. The video isn't shown in correct orientation if its `VideoProperties.Orientation` is different from `VideoOrientation.Normal` (e.g. `VideoOrientation.Rotate90`). Those videos can be recorded by native camera app while holding the phone vertically. It's strange that Windows Phone native video player also has the same problem and is always locked in landscape mode (this doesn't happen with IOS or Android video player). My question is : Does Windows Phone native video player use the same API to play video like `MediaElement`? In that case, is it possible that that API will be updated to fix this problem in future Windows Phone update? I need to confirm those things to make a suitable workaround for this problem.